# Make blind spot monitor radars work at all speeds

Tags: mazda, cx9, blind-spot-monitoring

I have a 2013 Mazda CX-9. The blind spot monitor works after 32 km/h (20 mph): [image]

Is there a way to hack it so it works for all speeds?

Comment: I don't know how it can be done or even if it can be done. Seems strange to me, though ... my wife's Cadillac XT5's blind spot works all the time ... even annoyingly so. I don't know why Mazda built there's so it doesn't.